# Add a timestamp column to output table in Python Dash Example

Tags: python, json, pandas, plotly-dash

I am trying to add a timestamp column to the table shown in this Python Dash Example:

https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/main/apps/dash-image-annotation/app.py

The aim is to have a timestamp for each of the created objects.

So far, I managed to:

1. Create a new column in the output table (Line 48 of the Github code)
2. Trying to append a timestamp by adding this to the "modify_table_entries" function (line 466 in the Github code):

   ```
   annotations_table_data[0]["timestamp"] = time_passed(annotations_store_data["starttime"])
   ```

This gives me a timestamp only for the first entry in the output table:

[image]

I tried now however for several days now. I believe I have to somehow append the timestamp to each created object in this function of the code:

```
def modify_table_entries(
    previous_n_clicks,
    next_n_clicks,
    graph_relayoutData,
    annotations_table_data,
    image_files_data,
    annotations_store_data,
    annotation_type,
):
    cbcontext = [p["prop_id"] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if cbcontext == "graph.relayoutData":
        #debug_print("graph_relayoutData:", graph_relayoutData)
        #debug_print("annotations_table_data before:", annotations_table_data)
        if "shapes" in graph_relayoutData.keys():
            # this means all the shapes have been passed to this function via
            # graph_relayoutData, so we store them
            annotations_table_data = [
                shape_to_table_row(sh) for sh in graph_relayoutData["shapes"]
            ]            
        elif re.match("shapes\[[0-9]+\].x0", list(graph_relayoutData.keys())[0]):
            # this means a shape was updated (e.g., by clicking and dragging its
            # vertices), so we just update the specific shape
            annotations_table_data = annotations_table_shape_resize(
                annotations_table_data, graph_relayoutData
            )
        if annotations_table_data is None:
            return dash.no_update
        else:
            debug_print("annotations_table_data after:", annotations_table_data)
            annotations_table_data[0]["timestamp"] = time_passed(annotations_store_data["starttime"])
            return (annotations_table_data, image_files_data)
    image_index_change = 0
    if cbcontext == "previous.n_clicks":
        image_index_change = -1
    if cbcontext == "next.n_clicks":
        image_index_change = 1
    image_files_data["current"] += image_index_change
    image_files_data["current"] %= len(image_files_data["files"])
    if image_index_change != 0:
        # image changed, update annotations_table_data with new data
        annotations_table_data = []
        filename = image_files_data["files"][image_files_data["current"]]
        #debug_print(annotations_store_data[filename])
        for sh in annotations_store_data[filename]["shapes"]:
            annotations_table_data.append(shape_to_table_row(sh))
        return (annotations_table_data, image_files_data)
    else:
        return dash.no_update
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I looked at the code on github, I think you also need to refer to timestamp data in the following functions : `shape_to_table_row, default_table_row, table_row_to_shape`, and maybe to define a default/fallback value.

Comment: I tried to refer them, but the input data "sh" does not have a "timestamp", therefore having an error there. Can i create a seperate, internal timestamp variable in the def shape_to_table_row() and append it in that function directly? Or would it need to go through all the other functions...

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by setting default values. But actually after a second look, it seems shapes already have a `timestamp`, which defaults to the value of `starttime` from the 'annotations-store' (line 507). But on line 520 there is a call to `shape_data_remove_timestamp`, the function mentions that "_go.Figure complains if we include the 'timestamp' key when updating the figure_". So you can try to replace this function by another one that maps the timestamp to another fieldname which does not conflict with go, or just remove the call and completely rename the field.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies... Seems the latter is the most convenient option... Removing the call and rename the field with numerical time values maybe? I find it pretty complicated because everything seems so interconnected. But I will keep trying and thank you very much